# DIsplaying images forom MySQl using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

So i have a table with a column dedicated to the image source url's. The thing is when I display it like this

```
<div class="article-container">
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM alltables";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $queryResults=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($queryResults > 0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<div class = 'article-box'>
                <h3>".$row['RecipeName']."</h3>  
                <img src= ".$row['RecipeImage'];"/>
                <p>Serving Size:</p> <p>".$row['ServingSize']."</p> 
                <p>Prep Time:</p><p>".$row['PrepTime']."</p> 
                <a target='_new' href='".$row['UrlLinks']."'>View Recipe</a>
            </div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

The image wont show and instead im given a missing image icon on my web browser. What could i possibly be missing here?

Comment: does `$row['RecipeImage']` contain the full path like `/path/to/image.jpg` and the path and filename is correct and does exist on the server? if yes have those images read-permissions?

Comment: Ive displayed them successfully on other pages using <td><img class = "recipeimg" src="<?php echo $row['RecipeImage']; ?>"/></td> .                                                
 What i have in my database table are img source url links such as https://s23209.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Korean-Cheese-CornIMG_9994-400x400.jpg

Comment: What html does that code generate, what url is the correct url for the image(s) - what’s the difference? `What could i possibly be missing here?` debugging :).

Answer (score 0):

From what i know, the reason why images can not show is the image file is not located in the same location that is specified in your image tag or
the image does not have the same file name as specified in your image tag or
the image file is corrupt or damaged. Just in case try to clear cache in your browser.